# PHPMAILER no llega al webmail

Tags: php, phpmailer

Tengo un problema al configurar *PHPMailer*, ya busqué en Google y me contacté con mi proveedor de hosting pero estos no pueden resolver mi problema, dicen que tengo que revisar mi código pero resulta que el código lo tengo bien (por lo menos eso creo) así que agradecería si ustedes me pueden dar una mano.

Pd: En la configuración MX del hosting hay cuatro opciones:

1. Configuración detectada automáticamente
2. **Intercambiador de correo loca**
3. Intercambiador de correos de copias de seguridad
4. Intercambiador de correo remoto

Yo tengo seleccionada la opción dos (en negritas).

Procedo a dejar mis scripts

**FORMULARIO HTML**

```
<div class="formulario-contacto" id="form-contact">
            <form name="formulario" method="POST" class="formulario" id="formulario" action="../enviarcorreo.php"> 
                <div>
                    <ul class="success" id="success"></ul>
                </div>
                <input type="text" required id="nombre" class="nombre" name="nombre" placeholder="Name:" minlength="3" maxlength="15">
                <input type="text" required id="apellido" class="apellido" name="apellido" placeholder="Lastname:" minlength="2" maxlength="50">
                <input type="email" required name="mail" id="mail" class="mail" placeholder="Mail:">
                <textarea name="texto" required id="texto" class="textarea" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Tell us your project..." minlength="50"></textarea>
                <button type="submit" class="btn-send" id="submit" name="submit">Send</button>
                <div>
                    <ul class="error" id="error"></ul>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
```

**Archivo PHP**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $nombre = htmlspecialchars($_POST['nombre'],ENT_QUOTES);
    $apellido = htmlspecialchars($_POST['apellido'],ENT_QUOTES);
    $correo = $_POST['mail'];
    $texto = $_POST['texto'];
}

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'PHPMailer/Exception.php';
require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php';
require 'PHPMailer/SMTP.php';

// Instantiation and passing `true` enables exceptions
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
    //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;                      // Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP();                                            // Send using SMTP
    $mail->Host       = 'gator4021.hostgator.com';                    // Set the SMTP server to send through
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username   = 'agency@programmark.com';                     // SMTP username
    $mail->Password   = '***';                               // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';         // Enable TLS encryption; `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` encouraged
    $mail->Port       = 465;                                    // TCP port to connect to, use 465 for `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` above

    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom($correo);
    $mail->addAddress('agency@programmark.com');     // Add a recipient             

    // Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = "Correo enviado desde mi pagina web";
    $mail->Body    = "<h3> $nombre $apellido </h3><br /> <p>$texto</p>";
    $mail->send();
?>
```

**Javascript (jQuery)**

```
$('#formulario').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        let formulario = $(this).serialize();
        let nombre = $('#nombre').val(),
            apellido = $('#apellido').val(),
            correo = $('#mail').val(),
            text = $('#texto').val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "../enviarcorreo.php",
                data: {name: nombre, lastname: apellido, email: correo, texto: text},
                success: function(data){
                    $('#formulario').trigger('reset');
                    alert('The form has been sent successfully!');
                },
                error: function(data){
                    alert('The form could not be sent')
                },  
            })  
    });
```

Necesito saber qué tengo mal ya que al momento de mandar el formulario me da el error de AJAX *the form could not be sent* y antes de eso me decía que si se había mandado pero cuando me fijaba en mi *Webmail* no aparecía, o sea que cuando me decía que todo funcionaba con éxito en realidad no era así porque nunca llegaban los mails.

PD: Desde mi *Webmail* podía mandar mail y también recibir pero los que no recibía eran los que enviaba desde mi pagina web.
Para que quede claro, yo puedo enviar un mail desde una cuenta "x" a la dirección de mi *Webmail* y este me va a llegar, desde la cuenta de *Webmail* puedo enviar un mail a la cuenta "x" pero si intento enviar el formulario de mi pagina web este no llega al *Webmail*.

Agradecería mucho cualquier consejo y mil gracias por la ayuda.

ACTUALIZO:

Buenas tardes a todos los que me contestaron la duda. Logré que al hacer click salga el alert diciendo que fue enviado correctamente pero todavía no me llegan los mails. Hice como dijo el usuario @Amedano e implemente un `console.log(data)` en la parte de succe, al momento de dar click en el boton send el consonle.log aparecía diciendo lo siguiente `Invalid address:  (From): <br>`
From es del remitente y yo ponía la variable del correo que el usuario que se registraba ponía en el formulario, pero al leer eso me di cuenta que no puedo enviar un mail desde la cuenta de otra persona a menos que tenga su contraseña jaja que inexperto.
En fin, mi pregunta es que tengo que poner en donde dice `$mail->setFrom('');?` pongo el mail de mi servidor mail.dominio.com? o como solucionaría este problema?
Desde ya muchas gracias

Comment: hostgator tiene un articulo hablando de este tema [PHPMailer](https://soporte-latam.hostgator.com/hc/es-419/articles/360033787632--C%C3%B3mo-configurar-el-PHPMailer-#requisitos) en el cual al final te dice que si tienes problemas agreges.. `$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
$mail->Debugoutput = 'html';` para ver los posibles errores y el motivo por el cual no se envia el correo... una ves te marque el porque, bucas la solucion o editas tu pregunta agregando esta informacion para poderte ayudar..

Comment: La parte `error` de las peticiones Ajax son errores de servidor, no necesariamente de que el envío de PHPMailer funcione o no. Por tanto, si tenías error ahí podía deberse a otra cosa (un error de sintaxis en PHP por ejemplo, o que no encuentra la clase de PHPMailer). Entonces, lo primero es verificar que no hay error de servidor en cuanto tal. Luego, puedes aumentar el nivel de Debug de PHPMailer como sugiere @Byro y poner un `console.log(data);` en la parte del `success` y revisar la consola para ver qué error está ocurriendo exactamente. Como dije antes, si no ves nada en consola ...

Comment: ... al hacer eso, **el problema principal es que tu código PHP en sí no funciona**, por errores de servidor, y debes corregir esos errores. Creo que eso no queda claro en tus procesos de depuración, y podrías estar intentando hacer funcionar un script que en sí estaría fallando por **otros problemas** que no necesariamente tienen que ver con PHPMailer. La petición Ajax entraría en `error` por algo tan simple como que olvides de cerrar una línea PHP con `;` y el que entre ahí no tiene que ver necesariamente con que el correo se envíe o no.

Comment: Con un poco de rigor, controlando errores en el flujo del código de servidor tendrías a mano el motivo del error. Pero eso no ocurre. Te aconsejo que controles tu código, verificando el estado del método `send()` de PHPMailer, o bien mediante un bloque `try ... catch` , para capturar los errores e informar de ellos en la salida. El control de errores es importante cuando escribes código, de lo contrario, dejas al usuario en el limbo cuando ocurre algún error. El usuario agradece ser informado, sea de errores, sea de que su proceso terminó exitosamente. Nada de eso se está haciendo.

Comment: Prueba comentando las líneas `$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';` y `$mail->Port = 465;` Si lo envía, entonces el problema es configuración del protocolo de seguridad, SSL o TLS.